# Intellij MYSQl how to connect with controller class?

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

I'm new to intelliJ, just switched from eclipse. I have a few question:
I have gone to the project settings, to the libraries and added MYSQl connection. Also under modules and dependencies I have the mySql connector.
I have tried the following code in eclipse:

```
String dbUsername = "root";
    String dbPassword = "12frimyux09";
    String URL = "127.0.0.1";
    String port = "3306";
    String dbName = "university";
    //Connection con;
    String SQL;
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + URL + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?verifyServerCertificate=false&useJDBCComplaintTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    Properties property  = new Properties();

        property.setProperty ("user", dbUsername);
        property.setProperty("password", dbPassword);
        property.setProperty("useSSL", "false");
        property.setProperty("autoReconnect", "true");

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbURL, property);
```

worked just fine, but doesn't work with intellij (I put the code in the controller class), even tried using try and catch, still no luck, I get the following error.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0pgo.jpg)
Also in eclipse when I use Integer.parseInt I get alot of suggestions, but with intellij I get error and no suggestions, tried cntrl space and cntrl p, also went to file, settings, code completion and set all the ticks under parameter info, what am I doing wrong, why isn't intellji completing me???

Comment: 1. You need to correctly set up project that the folder where your source files are located marked as **source roots**: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#project_tool_window 2. Check that the file is not corrupted by bad encoding. Set it to UTF-8 for the files: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html

Comment: Thank you, but still no change

Comment: Actually I corrected some of the code and placed these lines within a method, but now I get an exception that I dont have jdbc driver despite the fact that I added the library of mysql connector.